# Why I can only access half of RAM whatever the total is?

Tags: ubuntu, ram

I have an Intel 11700 with 4*32 GB RAM.

When 4 physical RAM slots are filled, BIOS, `htop`, `sudo lshw`, `sudo dmidecode dmesg` (whatever command I use to display the total RAM on the system) all display that I have 128 GB RAM.

However, I can only use 57.2 GB, i.e. approximately half of the available RAM.

I tested this by using `malloc()` in C and creating files in `tmpfs`. The former finally returns a `NULL` pointer, and the latter finally displays that the device is out of space.

More strangely, if I only install one or two RAM modules, i.e. 32 or 64 GB, I still can only use about half of the RAM, i.e. 12.1 or 28.7 GB.

Comment: @StephenKitt I configure it in the way```sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=80G tmpfs ~/tmp/```

Comment: What does `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory` show? If it’s not 0, what does `sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio` show?

Comment: @StephenKitt oh yes it works. I ask my apprentice and he tells me that he configured it as  2 and forgot to restore it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `malloc` fail, especially at 50% occupation, is a symptom of strict allocations, *i.e.* disabled [overcommit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/mm/overcommit-accounting.html). This is controlled by [the `vm.overcommit_memory` sysctl](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#overcommit-memory), and can be seen with

```
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory
```

If that indicates 2, the kernel will prevent overcommits, so heap resizes, `mmap`s etc. will fail when allocating (rather than when the memory is actually used). The limit is set to swap plus [`vm.overcommit-kbytes`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#overcommit-kbytes) or [`vm.overcommit-ratio`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#overcommit-ratio) (as a percentage of physical memory).

To get the behaviour you’re expecting, set `vm.overcommit_memory` to 0.